# Changing background colors in my folders

Tags: folders

How can I change the folder color from black to grey in my folders. I am using OS X 10.6.8. I tried going to View, Show View Options and there is nothing there for me to change colors

Answer (score 1):

If the option isn't under 'Show View Options', make sure your folder view is set to icons. You can't change the colour in list view.